# Statistical analysis on Bell shaped (Gaussian) curve

Tags: image-processing, opencv, statistics, plot, gaussian

In my application I am getting images (captured by a high speed camera) containing projections of some light sources on the screen.

1-My first task is to plot a PDF or intensity distribution plot for the light intensity, which should come as bell shape or Gaussian, since at the center the light intensity will be maximum and at the ends it will be diminishing. Like this(just for example, not the exact case for me):
 [image]

In worst cases I will be having a series of light sources illuminated simultaneously.  In such cases theoretically I should get overlapping bell or Gaussian curves, some what like this: [image]

How do I plot such a curve given the Images of light projection (like the one in the figure)?

2-After the Gaussian curve is drawn, the next job is to analyze the same  such as finding width and height of the curve.    How do I go for this?

I want an executable for this application, so a solution given by MATLAB or similar tool is not acceptable to my client. Also i want the solution to work in real time or near real time.

I guess OpenCV can be used here. But before I start I would like to know opinions of Image processing gurus on this forum. Especially for the step -1 above, I need some inputs.

Any pointers here?

Rgrds,

Heshsham

Note: Image is taken from http://pentileblog.com.

Comment: There's no reason why intensity must follow the normal distribution. You could make that assumption but I see nothing to be gained from that. To make progress you are going to need to be more precise over the analysis that you intend to do. At the  moment this is too vague.

Comment: For the time being I have figured out how I will be progressing for part 1. I have to scan the image in a line and note down the pixel values. When plotted, it will be a bell shaped curve. I will be using openCV for reading and processing the image.

Comment: @gpuguy you should try to be more precise with your question. Right now it is not easy to understand what inputs do you have and you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @Simon I just want to plot the Intensity Profile for the Blob. I am sorry I  used the term PDF somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I solved it:

Algorithms is as follows:

1-use cvSampleLine for reading a particual line of image

2- use cvMinMaxLoc to know the maximum  pixel value in a line

3- Note which of these lines is having highest pixel value. Lets say line no. 150

4- Plot pixel value for line 150.

I used MATLAB for verifying my results and graphs, and the OpenCV result is exactly the same. 
Thanks for your suggestions guys.

Answer (score 0):

To get the 1D Gaussian out of the 2D one, you can do a couple of things depending on what you want exactly.
- You could sum over every column of the image;
- You could find the local maximum in intensity and copy the intensity profile of that row of the image only;
- You could threshold the image (in case your maximum will be saturated and therefore a plateau), determine the center of gravity of the remaining blob, and copy that row's intensity profile;
- You could threshold, find contours, determine multiple local maxima, and grab multiple intensity profiles if the application calls for it (e.g. if the blobs are not horizontally aligned).

To get the height and width, it's pretty easy, just find the maximum and the points left and right of it where the curve drops to half of the maximum. The standard deviation is the distance between the two points divided by 2.35 ([wikipedia link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_function)).

Comment: Your second para explains well what I want in part 2 of my question.